# Does the clearing of the specific interupt mask postpone or disregard interrupts while it's cleared?

Tags: arduino, interrupt, avr

I have a *piece of code* in Arduino (Avr) which I want to execute without it being interrupted by *an interrupt that also operates on variables used in this piece of code*. I don't want that interrupt to be lost while the piece of code is being executed; rather, I want to have the interrupt be postponed for a short time. I only want to postpone this one interrupt, not all interrupts.

Right now *I'm clearing that interrupt mask and setting it again* after the code is finished. Is this working? This is what the code looks like:

Piece of code I don't want being interrupted by that interrupt (timer1 overflow interrupt, in this case):

```
  TIMSK1 = 0; //Set Timer1 Mask off. Just postponed ???? I hope so.
  int c = buffer[reading_pointer]; 
  reading_pointer = (reading_pointer + 1)%SIZE_OF_BUFFER;
  something_on_buffer = false;
  //buffer and something_on_buffer are set on Timer1 interrupt. 
  TIMSK1 |= (1 << TOIE1); //Enable timer1 again.
```

`something_on_buffer`  and `buffer` are set also on Timer1, there would be a conflict if the interrupt executes in the middle of reading the buffer and setting `something_on_buffer` in this piece of code, and that's the reason I want to postpone Timer1 interrupts for this few lines of code. Just to be sure. How to do this? Is this the right way?

Answer (score 0):

Your approach looks fine.

Generally, processors have a flag register for the interrupts, and a register to enable the interrupts. At each step, the processor checks the and of the flags and enable bits to see if it should run an interrupt. That is, the enable bits don't control whether the flag is set, only if the set flag induces the interrupt to run.

If you enable an interrupt by setting the bit and the flag is already set, the interrupt with run before the next machine instruction.

If the interrupt is not enabled, the flag bit can still be set by the condition.